# Using dammed river for Mikveh

Tags: halacha, technology, mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah, yoreh-deah

Is it a halachic option to use a lake that was made from a dammed river for a mikveh? So the river goes from the land to  the ocean but it is blocked by a dam to create a lake, would it be okay for mikveh (either for Niddah or other purposes)?

Comment: https://psak.yctorah.org/does-a-dammed-river-have-the-status-of-a-mikveh/

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2023/09/mrs-ethel-abrams-ettel-haivriya-of-clarksdale-mississippi/

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel what an amazing story! Thanks for sharing.